# cd . causing exit when running with set -e in zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm having a weird issue with a zsh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# in ~/bin/script.sh
set -e
echo before
cd .
echo after
```

I'm getting some odd behavior - it looks like `cd .` is failing in some directories:

```
% cd ~
% ~/bin/script.sh
before
after
% echo $?
0
% cd ~/Projects
% ~/bin/script.sh
before
% echo $?
1
```

I'm not sure what it is about the directory that's causing `cd .` to fail:

```
% ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x  173 rampion  staff  5882 Mar 14 15:13 ./
```

Even odder, if I use `&&` to chain on `cd .` succeeding, it succeeds

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# in ~/bin/script2.sh
set -e
echo before
cd . && echo during
echo after
```

Like so:

```
% cd ~
% ~/bin/script2.sh
before
during
after
% echo $?
0
% cd ~/Projects
% ~/bin/script2.sh
before
during
after
% echo $?
0
```

I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Is the given `ls -ld` output for `~/Projects`? Do you have any `chpwd` hooks defined?

Comment: Does your script have DOS line endings? It would explain why `script2.sh` works (the carriage return is appended to "during", not "."), but I can't think why that would cause problems only in certain directories.